# Thunderbird on dual boot - profile inaccessible

Tags: dual-boot, thunderbird, .profile

I'm a first-time Ubuntu user - I've just put 13.10 on my XP system as a dual boot.

I used Thunderbird portable on the XP machine (easy to recover every time you need a rebuild!), and I understand that you can use the same profile on Ubuntu - sharing the profile location by indicating its location in the profiles.ini file.  So I did this using -profilemanager, and it worked nicely. I could access exactly the same data on Ubuntu as I could on Windows.

However, after I turned off and rebooted, I got this message when I started Thunderbird:

'Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded - it may be missing or inaccessible'

I looked at the profile.ini file with a text editor - it hadn't changed and was still pointing to the right directory. If I deleted it with -profilemanager and re-installed, it worked fine for that session. I could drop Thunderbird and start it again - no trouble. But if I re-booted, I lost the profile and had to re-establish it - although the profile.ini file hadn't changed.

I wonder if this is some kind of privileges issue? Whatever it is, I can't think of any more things to try. Has someone out there got any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response!    I assume that by 'purge and reinstall you mean remove Thunderbird?  On which system?   Given that I have quite a lot of time invested in the Windows build I am loth to rebuild this.  I have a simpler Ubuntu - how would you recommend that I remove and re-install Thunderbird on that?

Comment: OK - I have removed Thunderbird from Ubuntu using the Software Manager and specifying 'all files removed'.   Then I rebooted.    Then I installed it again using Software Manager.      When I clicked on the icon, I got the same error message - 'Profile cannot be loaded'.   So I used terminal mode to load Thunderbird -profilemanager, and found my original profile name there.             This suggests that I have not fully unloaded Thunderbird. Is there a better way to purge it?

Comment: will that purge my existing installation? - anyway, I did it and it said 'existing installation already there - adding gnome support'.

Comment: I used software centre to re-install - it said that thunderbird was already installed, so I uninstalled it and am now rebooting

Comment: Dont you like to use Terminal? when use terminal, it is easy to see the error messages. You just need to copy commands from here and then right click on terminal prompt and select paste. Then enter. Can you use terminal at least for this purpose only?

Comment: OK - same problem. I uninstalled with software manager, and then installed using terminal with your 'gnome-support' line. That installed ok - I tried to run thunderbird from terminal, and got the same error message - 'Profile cannot be loaded'.  So I tried profilemanager and found my original profile still there.  I do not know how to completely purge my thunderbird installation so that I get a clean new install...

Comment: So now run this : `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support && sudo apt-get install thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support`. Copy this and paste there and press enter. That configurations of thunderbird can be removed by purging. With software center it cannot be done. So here the thing that is being tried is to remove thunderbird configurations. Try and see weather it works. If not solved yet, then the problem is in settings.

Comment: Remove previous comments. Discussion is extending.

Comment: OK - I tried running purge on the terminal, rebooting and then running install. The profile was still there, with the same error -  'cannot be loaded'.  So I then deleted the profile in profilemanager, then ran your 'purge and install' command line in terminal. There was then no profile, so I added one, pointing the profile at the Windows data file as before.  And as before, Thunderbird worked fine in Ubuntu at first, then when I rebooted,    stopped working with the same 'profile cannot be loaded' message.

Comment: I wonder if the mix of capital letters and lower case in the profile directory name (which Windows ignores) is causing problems for Ubuntu?

Comment: Very kind of you to take the trouble to respond! I'm not sure what you mean about the 'mail service' - isn't it Thunderbird?  (sorry for the delay - I've been in Windows changing the name cases...)

Comment: I use an ISP - NTLWorld. So the addresses will be nnn@ntlworld.com.

Comment: See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingGmailWithEvolution)

Comment: Hmm...that sounds as if you think my Thunderbird mail isn't working. It was set up working under Windows, and still works there. When I set it up under Ubuntu I just pointed the Ubuntu profile to the same Windows library as the Windows Thunderbird, and it worked fine under Ubuntu. I could send and receive mail. My Pop and SMTP ports are 110 and 25 respectively - and that seems to work. I can start and stop Thunderbird as often as I like in a single Ubuntu session, and it will work.

Comment: What I can't do is turn the machine off, reboot Ubuntu and have Thunderbird working immediately. If I reboot, it can no longer load the profile, though it seems to see it quite happily in profilemanager. I have to delete and re-input the profile connection to the Windows directory, and then it will work perfectly. There is some kind of  Ubuntu connection problem which occurs if I reboot...

Comment: In the file browser press Ctrl+H . This will show hidden folders. In the `/home/yourusername`, there is a folder `.Thunderbird`. All the data are stored in it. The content in that folder should be open. Not locked. See that folder and weather have abnormalities.( When locked, there is a sign of a lock on the files.)

Comment: There is a .home folder, and inside that there is a .thunderbird folder. This just has a single profile.ini file inside it. The profile.ini looks reasonable - it has StartWithLastProfile=1, IsRelative=0 and a pathname. There is no lock.

Comment: Ok. try with running `sudo thunderbird` in terminal. That may open thunderbird. See weather it also having this problem. If that not open thunderbird,run `sudo /usr/bin/thunderbird`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - my wife called me for a meal...Both those attempts failed with the usual 'profile cannot be loaded' message. I think that there is some misdirection somewhere - maybe in Thunderbird.  It's getting a bit late at this end, so I'd like to close the work for today, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have just done the same thing. Created a dual boot machine with XP on one partition and Linux on the other. Then I pointed Thunderbird on each partition to the profile on the XP partition. When starting the Android Thunderbird I got the missing profile error. But i found that if I first clicked on the XP partition drive while in Android everything worked ok. I am now trying to work out how to initiate the XP drive when booting the Android ... all new to me!

Answer (score 0):

The Question is a bit older, but still worth an answer.

The partition where the Thunderbird-profile is stored must be mounted, otherwise Thunderbird can not load the profile.

**Example:**

I have my Thunderbird-profile stored on a Windows Partition (NTFS).
I created a folder named DATA in my home-directory. This folder is my mount-point.

Then I added a line to `/etc/fstab` with `sudo nano fstab`

```
UUID=01CAFB06CD224070  /home/mook/DATA  ntfs  rw,noexec  0 0
```

With this additional line in `/etc/fstab` the partition where the profile is stored will be auto-mounted during boot and Thunderbird is able to load the profile.

You can find out the correct UUID for your partition with `sudo blkid`.

**Note:**

The partition I mount is not my Windows-system-partition, it is a pure data-partition. Normally I never mount my Windows-system-partition to Ubuntu as I could accidentally destroy or corrupt my Windows. But mounting the Windows-system-partition is possible in the same way, you just have to be more careful then.