# Thunderbird profile on Ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, thunderbird

I am trying to use the same profile on Ubuntu and Windows 7. I moved the profile to a partition accessible by both systems. I can load it on windows 7 without any problem. Idem in Ubuntu. If I boot on windows 7 Thunderbird is working. If I reboot on Ubuntu and try to launch Thunderbird I have: 'Your Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.'. In clear, Thunderbird is working on both system accessing the profile but when I load it in windows 7 once and go back to Ubuntu the profile cannot be loaded anymore (I have to recreate a profile pointing to my partition)
Any idea?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/398118/thunderbird-on-dual-boot-profile-inaccessible?rq=1

Comment: See if you can actually mount your partition first.  I have an issue where Windows will cache something on my Data named Partition.  Making anything you need on that drive completely inaccessible.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy thnaks for the link; but there is no answer in the link you added. nice try but not helpful.

Comment: @Virusboy Yes my disk is mounted.. still searching.

Comment: Have you edited that file to point to the moved profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real solution!

I moved my profile to my windows OS drive. Reset my Thunderbird profiles in windows and Ubuntu to point to the new profile location and it is working perfectly (though the windows OS drive have to be mounted).

Still no idea why it is not working on my Data drive...